# Confuse of graphql. It is database level querying or API level querying

Tags: api, graphql

I am reading about graphql(facebook) in original website. I am confuse that graphql can filter to database query(MySQL...etc)? Or it can just filter for json API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL is just a query language (that has a defined specification) that a client uses to query a server. If a server implements the GraphQL specification, then clients can query it using GraphQL.

Even though GraphQL was designed for (and mostly used as) a language for use between client apps and application servers for data, there is nothing stopping you from putting up a GraphQL layer between a database and anything that queries that database. There are some projects that help you do this like https://github.com/stems/join-monster.

But, if you're just interested in standard usage of GraphQL, I recommend that you peruse some tutorials: https://www.howtographql.com/